# Trying to setup Windows Jenkins agent, but can't find "Windows Slave" plugin available

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

Trying to follow https://linuxhowtoguide.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-setup-jenkins-slave-on-windows.html to setup Windows Jenkins agent. On that instruction, Windows Slave plugin is specified to be installed, but it is not available from plugin "Available" tab. Any idea? Should WMI Windows Agent be installed instead? But that is an agent plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this - https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-slaves

The plugin name is "WMI Windows Agents" and Id is "windows-slave".

You need to make sure you Jenkins can reach this plugin URL.

Once the plugin is installed, a new launch type is available in the agent configuration. Once the agent configuration is saved, Jenkins will reconnect the agent(slave) using the plugin

Comment: Thank you Pankaj

Comment: Can you also accept the answer please if you happy with it?